# Random Forest Classifier accuracy doesn't get higher than 50%

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am very new to machine learning and I am trying to classify this [UCI Heart Disease Dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/heart+Disease) using sklearn's random forest classifier. My approach is very basic, and I wanted to ask how I could improve my accuracy with the algorithm (some tips, links, etc.). My accuracy tops out at about 50% every time. Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random as random
import sklearn
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

df = pd.read_excel('/Users/Mady/Documents/ClevelandData.xlsx')
df.replace('?', -99999, inplace=True)

labels = df.iloc[:,-1]
labels = labels.values

df.drop(df.columns[len(df.columns)-1], axis=1, inplace=True)
riskFactors = df.values

random.seed(123)
random.shuffle(labels)
random.seed(123)
random.shuffle(riskFactors)

labels_train = labels[:(int(len(labels) * 0.8))]
labels_test = labels[(int(len(labels) * 0.8)):]

riskFactors_train = riskFactors[:(int(len(riskFactors) * 0.8))]
riskFactors_test = riskFactors[(int(len(riskFactors) * 0.8)):]

model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 1000)
model.fit(riskFactors_train,labels_train)
predicted_labels = model.predict(riskFactors_test)
acc = accuracy_score(labels_test,predicted_labels)
print(acc)
```

Comment: explore your data first. look for patterns that you think your model should be able to estimate. what makes you think your dataset is estimable beyond a 50% accuracy rate?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. This question may be too broad for this forum. I suggest posting to Code Review or Data Science. https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There is some principal trouble with you data or labels. Could you please provide some sample from the date and label?

Comment: I think you messed up when you are shuffling the labels and riskFactors, for consistency, you should try to use the `train_test_split` provided by sklearn.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am definitely a newbie to this as I got to 80% simply by using the train_test_split and removing the random part(there must have been some error there).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by removing the random part as there must have been some error there.
As suggested by Yulin Zhang, I used the `train_test_split` provided by sklearn.